# php curl_setopt() returns json data with "1" on end

Tags: php, json, curl

so I have a curl_setopt that is pulling a json file just fine with php. It does this with one exception, at the end of the json data there is a one (1) on the end after the last '}'. This "1" is not apparent in the url call by itself without using curl though. So it seems my curl_setopt is not configured properly. Can someone help with this?

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $domain.$args);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
$json = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

the *$domain.$args* is working fine as I can echo out this variable setup and produce the json manually via browser without the 1.

appreciate the help

/**** edit after suggestions ****/

I tried the suggestion below of adding:

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

this just ended up changing the entire json output, not just adding a "1" on the end of the response:

```
"{\"data\":[{\"Name\":\"A3\",\"SeoName\":\"a3\"},{\"Name\":\"A4\",\"SeoName\":\"a4\"},{\"Name\":\"A5\",\"SeoName\":\"a5\"},{\"Name\":\"A6\",\"SeoName\":\"a6\"},{\"Name\":\"A7\",\"SeoName\":\"a7\"},{\"Name\":\"A8\",\"SeoName\":\"a8\"},{\"Name\":\"allroad\",\"SeoName\":\"allroad\"},{\"Name\":\"Q5\",\"SeoName\":\"q5\"},{\"Name\":\"Q5 hybrid\",\"SeoName\":\"q5-hybrid\"},{\"Name\":\"Q7\",\"SeoName\":\"q7\"},{\"Name\":\"R8\",\"SeoName\":\"r8\"},{\"Name\":\"RS 5\",\"SeoName\":\"rs-5\"},{\"Name\":\"RS 7\",\"SeoName\":\"rs-7\"},{\"Name\":\"S4\",\"SeoName\":\"s4\"},{\"Name\":\"S5\",\"SeoName\":\"s5\"},{\"Name\":\"S6\",\"SeoName\":\"s6\"},{\"Name\":\"S7\",\"SeoName\":\"s7\"},{\"Name\":\"S8\",\"SeoName\":\"s8\"},{\"Name\":\"SQ5\",\"SeoName\":\"sq5\"},{\"Name\":\"TT\",\"SeoName\":\"tt\"},{\"Name\":\"TTS\",\"SeoName\":\"tts\"}]}"
```

Comment: Are you sure that the Response have not generally a problem with the "1" at the end? Check the Request over http://secondchoice.de/ or http://web-sniffer.net/ and show if the "1" at the end here too. **USE** `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` (true)!

Comment: Rest of the code? Where's the printing part? And `_RETURNTRANSFER`.

Comment: If you do not set `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` then `curl_exec()` will dump what it retrieves to stdout and return a boolean value which you store in `$json`, and when you do `echo true;` the output will be 1.

Answer (score 7):

Use this:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

Answer (score -1):

Fix but not ideal is to `substr()` it to strip out the 1.

```
substr($result, 0, strlen($result) - 1);
```